# NSString takes substrings

Tags: objective-c

I have the following NSString in objective C:

```
[["123"], ["456"], ["adg"]]
```

and I would like to separate into differents strings like this :

```
aux = 123;

aux2 = 456;

aux3 = adg;
```

Please, anyone can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can call

```
NSArray *arrayOfSubStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

then loop through for each string in the array and remove the square brackets by calling

```
aux =  [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[arrayOfSubStrings ObjectAtIndex:x] withString:@""]
```

[See NSString Doc for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"[[\"123\"], [\"456\"], [\"adg\"]]";
NSString *new = [[str substringFromIndex:4]substringToIndex:7];


new will be 123
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the string format that you're parsing I'd highly recommend looking at [JSON](http://json.org/) and using [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse it. This is more preferable than re-inventing the wheel by defining your own format to store primitive objects.